# Property to stop textboxes from resizing

Tags: jquery, css

I have an HTML in which I have text boxes and they are resizeable on chrome.

I want to avoid that; is there any property in jQuery which we can use which makes text areas not expandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use jquery you have to:

```
$('#textarea-id').css('resize', 'none');
```

Otherwise, as I suggest, use simply CSS:

```
#textarea-id {
    resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for jQuery, you can use CSS' [resize property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize):

```
textarea{
    resize: none
}
```

Note the accepted vertical and horizontal values that will allow the textarea to be resizable only in that orientation

Answer (score 1):

You can use below css property

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```